# Where is the logic of react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Recently I've started reading react hooks code and I see this.

```
function useState(initialState) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useState(initialState);
}
function useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init);
}
function useRef(initialValue) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useRef(initialValue);
}
function useEffect(create, deps) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useEffect(create, deps);
}
function useLayoutEffect(create, deps) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useLayoutEffect(create, deps);
}
function useCallback(callback, deps) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useCallback(callback, deps);
}
function useMemo(create, deps) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useMemo(create, deps);
}
function useImperativeHandle(ref, create, deps) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useImperativeHandle(ref, create, deps);
}
function useDebugValue(value, formatterFn) {
  {
    var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
    return dispatcher.useDebugValue(value, formatterFn);
  }
}
```

The dispatcher is an object that initialized by resolveDispatcher().

```
function resolveDispatcher() {
  var dispatcher = ReactCurrentDispatcher.current;

  if (!(dispatcher !== null)) {
    {
      throw Error( "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component..." );
    }
  }

  return dispatcher;
}
```

and ReactCurrentDispatcher is a object with one property that called `current`.

```
var ReactCurrentDispatcher = {
  /**
   * @internal
   * @type {ReactComponent}
   */
  current: null
};
```

now my question is how and where react handles the logic of hooks?
where is the logic of useImperativeHandle or ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, to answer questions like this I clone the repo and use `ag` or `git grep`:

```
(react) $ git grep useImperativeHandle
[...]
packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js:    useImperativeHandle<T>(
[...]
```

That leads me to [these mappings](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3dc41d8a2590768a6ac906cd1f4c11ca00417eee/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L2401-L2483) right here – the code for `useImperativeHandle`, for example, seems to be  [these three functions](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3dc41d8a2590768a6ac906cd1f4c11ca00417eee/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L1769-L1862).

Understanding how they work and interact with the React fiber system is another rabbit hole.